# Particle Hair Edit gets discarded when enabling "use modifier stack" in the emission tab

Tags: particles, hair

I just tried to render out some hair simulation for my character. When watching the simulation baked in the viewport everything looks fine. As soon as I hit the render animation button my hair gets slowly messed up more and more with each frame I render.

After a little research I came to the conculsion that it probably has something to do with the "use modifier stack" option in the emission tab of my particle system. The option was disabled for all my particle systems. Unfortunately when enabling the option now, all my particle edits are gone. I've spent a bunch of time for my particle edits so prefereably I would like to find a solution to keep my particle edits so I don't have to redo the work.

Is there any way t prevent blender form deleting my particle edits when enabling "use modifier stack" or is there any way to maybe transfer the particles back onto a duplicate of the mesh with the option turned on?

Is there any

Comment: You can transfer the edited hair to another mesh with the help of the [HairNet or Particle Hair Guides addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205226/convert-curve-to-particle-hair-guide). See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/210169/107598 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212876/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-hair-particle-look-like-a-mesh-ive-already-made/212962#212962 for details.