# Can you comb hair particles after they have been baked?

Tags: mesh, hair

I am having great difficulty understanding the later stages of workflow when it comes to the hair particle system.
Create a scalp mesh
Create a particle emitter type hair
I enable collisions on the emitter mesh, body etc... kiss good bye my shape keys :(
I was having problems with my model looking like smeagol from lord of the rings as the hair would clip the scalp even with the collision modifier enabled.
I have somewhat solved this by running the simulation and letting the hair not only fall into place but pop out of the scalp.

Now my problem is this:

Can I comb the particle hair system after I bake it?
I read somewhere I can but right now when I got to particle edit the hair is gone.
My issue is the hair looks decent but is in front of my 3d models face. If I convert to a mesh then it loses the children and overall aesthetic... but at least I can move the hair out of the face. There has got to be a better way.
Also, some of the top hairs look like tubes, if I make less children my model looks bald. I feel I am so close but am missing something.

I enclosed a picture of my character being rendered but the hair is all in her face. It took me an hour to simulate 1000 frames and baked just to get the hair to stop moving.

Any advice is appreciated, like what settings you use for damping collision etc. But also work flow... now that I get the hair the way I want it does it need to simulate every time I need to animate? Should I make another collision object just to "brush" the hair out the way.
Super frustrating all the tutorials cover mostly things I already know.[image]

Comment: AFAIK there is a bug that prevents that you can edit the particles (emitter & hair) after you baked/simulated them. Have a look at this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191147/cant-edit-cached-particles. If the hair looks like tubes you need to adjust the *Hair Shape > Diameter Root + Tip* settings. Also set in Eevee render settings *Hair > Hair Shape Type* to *Strip* to see the thickness of the hair in the viewport.

Comment: Thankyou so much it is good to know I am not going crazy! It kind of sucks but I guess I will try this work around thanks again!

Comment: The particle system is quite old and is going to be updated (node-based). The devs already started to improve it but then changed focus to the geometry nodes. So we need to be patient and hope the old bugs will be fixed in one of the next major versions of Blender.

Comment: About the workflow, it depends on how much realism you want & on how much movement there is (head shaking? upside-up? wind?). If your character just talks, eats & walks you need to simulate only a strand or two and/or the tips of the hair & keep all other hair particles stiff. The stiffness can be controlled by the weights (*Particle Edit* mode>*Weight* brush) & the *Pin Goal Strength* which affects all particles depending on their weights. If she does gymnastics or is outside where it's windy you want to make the hair fly. IIRC, edited hair also tries to keep its shape when it is simulated.