# Edit particle system at frame

Tags: rendering, particles, edit-mode, physics, hair

I'd like to let hair in a particle system fall by gravity, then cut the hair. Before gravity, I can't get the correct lengths. An incomplete work-around is to convert the particle system to mesh, then curve, then curves, then back to particle system again, but then the hair settings are changed and some things don't work anymore then. What's the best way to edit a particle system at a given frame? Saving the particle system and making the frame the default would also be ok. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try the HairNet add-on workaround. It's described in this question: [Can't Edit Cached Particles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/191147/107598)